# how to execute a php automatically on server

Tags: php, cron

i am trying to run a PHP automatically on a server every 15 minutes. The PHP should send mails to some contacts from a database. I have created the PHP and tested it and it's ready.

Now i dont know how to set it to run every 15 minutes.

I read some article about it on this website and i saw something about cronjob. I know the server where i stored my php has the stuff installed to run cronjobs but to be honest i dont know where to start this. I have a ftp where i upload the phps and a froxlor admin panel.

I hope someone can enlighten me with this 'next level' thing :D

Thank you very much,
Daniel!

Comment: This belongs on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: What about reading the documentation of froxlor or asking your service provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `crontab -e`, and add the below line:

```
*/15 * * * * /path/to/your/php/script
```

If you didn't add execute permission to your script, you need to add the php executive.

```
*/15 * * * * /path/to/php/executive /path/to/your/php/script
```

Comment: On the froxlor panel i have only email / SQL / Domains / FTP / Extras / Traffic / Support tickets

Comment: @PacuraruDaniel If you can't login to the server, then you can't to do this.

Comment: i can login to the floxlor admin panel and also to the ftp

Comment: @PacuraruDaniel Can you use the terminal?

Comment: no, im not where the server is, i can only do stuff via ftp and that froxlor panel that they use

Comment: @PacuraruDaniel Then you can't do this.

Comment: thank you very much, yes you were right i cannot do this, i just asked the guys from the hosting and they added the command line there and it is working perfect now :D

Answer (score 1):

Search for "CronJobs" in the admin panel. There should be a section there for adding cron jobs using the interface.

When you create the cron job, you will see that there are various options to define the time interval when the task is repeated.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small correction to what xdazz has to say:

```
*/15 * * * * php /path/to/your/php/script
```

You will need to prefix your script with "php".

Answer (score 0):

**add a cronjob**
example cronjob code for php script(in directadmin):

```
php /home/username/domains/domainaddress/public_html/phpfile.php
```

example cronjob code for php script(in cpanel):

```
php /home/username/public_html/phpfile.php
```